# Does this monument depict Koxinga?

Tags: china, identify-this, landmarks

The large horse rider monument located in Quanzhou, China here: [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=24.905126,118.619365&spn=0.00208,0.004128&t=w&z=19&lci=com.panoramio.all)

Is this monument depicting [Koxinga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koxinga) or someone else?

Can't find wiki articles or something in English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, yes it does.  If you click layers on Google Maps, and the Wikipedia layer, you'll also get photos taken in the area.  Several are from Panoramio, and are labelled "Zheng Cheng Gong" - [see an example](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/37812527).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koxinga):

> Koxinga (Lord of the Imperial Surname) is the customary Western
>   spelling[8] of the popular appellation of Zheng Chenggong,

So it would appear we've found our match :)

**EDIT - UPDATE**

If you then look at the [Wikipedia page for Quanzhou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanzhou), it informs us that:

> Notable Modern cultural sites include:
>       Da Ping Shan - The second tallest hill within the city limits, crowned with **an enormous equestrian statue of Zheng Chenggong**.

So that would seem to add confirmation to my findings.

**EDIT - FURTHER FINDINGS**

I've also found the following:

- [A blog with photos of it](http://myfuturepast.blogspot.co.nz/2010/06/historic-quanzhou-china.html), and links with information
- [more photos on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/myfuturepast/tags/zhengchenggongkoxingastatue/)
- And the [Frommers Travel Guide review of the statue](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/quanzhou/A36709.html)!

Comment: My link to the map contained these photos of Panoramio. My friend was also told that this is Koxinga. So I am looking for additional confirmation, not only from tourists. For example monument caption or something.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Generally a few independent tourists agreeing together would be correct, but I concede I've seen them wrong before. After a bit more research I've added another source, this time from a Wikipedia page.  Hope that helps!

Comment: and a few more sources added now